PHP Ratchet Websocket clients do not receive messages
I'm using Ratchet and I like its implementation. I'm trying to send a message to all clients connected using chat example class with MessageComponentInterface but after executing php script, nothing is sent to connected clients.
chat class:
<?php

namespace MyApp;

use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;

require('../vendor/autoload.php');

class ChatServer implements MessageComponentInterface
{
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
        $msg = "Connection established!\n";

        // send server log to shell
        echo $msg;
        $this->sendMessageToAll($msg);
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg)
    {
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            // if ($from != $client) {
            $client->send($msg);
            // }
        }
    }

    # new || this is the function I'd like to use to send messages to all clients
    # it works fine when clients connect but I'm not able to use it properly in notify.php
    public function sendMessageToAll($msg)
    {
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            echo "Sending message to {$client->resourceId} \n";
            $client->send($msg);
        }
    }
    # /new 

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, Exception $e)
    {
        $conn->close();
    }
}

server.php:
use MyApp\ChatServer;

require('../vendor/autoload.php');
require('./chat.php');

$app = new Ratchet\App('localhost', 8080);
$app->route('/chat', new ChatServer, array('*'));
$app->route('/echo', new Ratchet\Server\EchoServer, array('*'));
$app->run();

notify.php:
use MyApp\ChatServer;

require('./chat.php');

$message = "sending message from registerEvent";
echo $message;

$conn = new ChatServer();
$conn->sendMessageToAll($message);

I'm testing it separately because my goal is to create a function to send a message to all users connected when a new register is created in a database table.
How can I fix it to make it works properly according to my goal? I've been reading some questions about it but I still could not make it works.
Edit: chat.html
<body>

    <p>
        <label for="name">Name: </label>
        <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="input">Message: </label>
        <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your message" />
    </p>
    <hr>
    <div id="chat"></div>

    <script>
        
        let chat = document.getElementById('chat');
        let input = document.getElementById('input');
        const name = document.getElementById('name');
        const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/chat');

        socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {

            // here connected message is displayed but nothing is received
            // when notify.php is executed
            console.log(event.data);

            const data = JSON.parse(event.data);

            chat.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<p><b>" + data.name + " says: </b>" + data.message + "</p>");
        });

        // sending message
        input.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {

                const data = {
                    name: name.value,
                    message: this.value,
                };

                socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));
                this.value = '';
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>

I edited my question with frontend code. Do you think it's because of "message" event that's only triggered on onOpen() function in chat class?

Do the clients receive a message that's empty? Or just never any messages at all? Have you verified that the clients are all connected to the socket server? Can you show us how you're connecting them?

@ADyson I edited my question with frontend code. Please take a look.

Thanks. So, have you checked in the browser's Console for any errors when the messages are supposed to be received? Your test code in the server is sending a simple string, but your JavaScript code is expecting to receive a JSON string, and trying to decode it and print individual fields from with it - obviously that won't work (demo) .

Try sending some suitable structured data from PHP instead, e.g. $message = json_encode(["name" => "System", "message" =>"sending message from registerEvent"]); $conn = new ChatServer(); $conn->sendMessageToAll($message); and you might have more luck. And/or test sending messages directly between the clients, because the client-side code constructs a message with structure that the receiving code is expecting.

Also it looks like notify.php creates a new instance of ChatServer, while server.php creates its own. So possibly the clients are all connected to a different server instance. If you want to make a PHP program which sends chat messages, really that program needs to connnect to the socket server as another client ...there are several PHP websocket client libraries you could probably use for that.

@ADyson and IloGus ok I agree with both of you when you say a new instance is created. I get no errors on browser's console. Nothing. So it must be because of a new instance. Is there another method besides route() and run() that I could use to access sendMessageToAll() from the first instance?

This seems to be describing the same sort of scenario, and shows you an approach to achieve the same functionality - i.e. pushing a message from the server-side to all clients: http://socketo.me/docs/push

your variable $res is null because your sendMessageToAll funciton has no return you should implement some logic and return it

true, although that doesn't necessarily explain also why clients don't receive any data when the send() function is called from within there

Yes @IloGus. I realized that after I have created the question but as ADyson said, it doesn't explain why clients don't receive data.

This must be because, in notify.php, you use the same chat.php class, which reinstantiates the $clients, but the connections already established are managed by another instance (server.php). This documentation should help you Push Integration

ADyson and @IloGus ok I agree with both of you when you say a new instance is created. I get no errors on browser's console. Nothing. So it must be because of a new instance. Is there another method besides route() and run() that I could use to access sendMessageToAll() from the first instance?

I think you need to completely rethink the architecture of your project to be able to manage client connections. Here's an example of how to store connections in a database: Ratchet Store Connection of User & Send Message Outside of Server Instance
Maybe you can also implement some clients management with Redis or create an ‘admin route’ to react differently when a message is posted...
